# Searching text for multiple phrases python

Tags: python, string, pdf, search, text

I am currently attempting to search through multiple pdfs for certain pieces of equipment. I have figured out how to parse the pdf file in python along with the equipment list. I am currently having trouble with the actual search function. The best way I found to do it online was to tokenize the text and the search through it with the keywords (code below), but unfortunately some of the names of the equipment are multiple words long, causing those names to be tokenized into meaningless words like "blue" and "evaporate" which are found many times in the text and thus saturate the returns. The only way I have thought of to deal with this is to only look for unique words in the names of the equipment and remove the more common ones, but I was wondering if there was a more elegant solution as even the unique words have a tendency to have multiple false returns per document.

Mainly, I am looking for way to search through a text file for phrases of words such as "Blue Transmitter 3", without parsing that phrase into ["Blue", "Transmitter", "3"]

here is what I have so far

```
import PyPDF2
import nltk
from nltk import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import re

#open up pdf and get text
pdfName = 'example.pdf'
read_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfName)
text = ""
for i in range(read_pdf.getNumPages()):
    page = read_pdf.getPage(i)
    text += "Page No - " + str(1+read_pdf.getPageNumber(page)) + "\n"
    page_content = page.extractText()
    text += page_content + "\n"

#tokenize pdf text
tokens = word_tokenize(text)
punctuations = ['(',')',';',':','[',']',',','.']
stop_words = stopwords.words('english')
keywords = [word for word in tokens if not word in stop_words and not word in punctuations]

#take out the endline symbol and join the whole equipment data set into one long string
lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('equipment.txt')]
totalEquip = " ".join(lines)

tokens = word_tokenize(totalEquip)
trash = ['Black', 'furnace', 'Evaporation', 'Evaporator', '500', 'Chamber', 'A']
searchWords = [word for word in tokens if not word in stop_words and not word in punctuations and not word in trash]

for i in searchWords:
    for word in splitKeys:
        if i.lower() in word.lower():
            print(i)
            print(word + "\n")
```

Any help or ideas yall might have would be much appreciated

Comment: Just realized it might not be clear, splitKeys is the data set of tokens from the pdf file

Comment: What is your input and what is your desired output?

Comment: @FailSafe my inputs are the pdf file to be searched and the text file containing the list of equipment, both of which are constants in my code.
Desired output would be a list of all the pieces of equipment mentioned in the pdf file

Comment: What I mean is, give us a sample of what your input looks like and from it, what your desired output is. Like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55126197/python-regex-match-a-line-and-replace/

Comment: my input would be a string of text, such as: "this is the content of a pdf containing a bunch of different information, such as pieces of equipment. One such piece of equipment is the Blue Machine 7, a very import piece of machinery." and it would also be a list of equipment parsed into different pieces of equipment, such as: [Purple hammer, pink mallet, Blue Machine 7]. I would like to search the text for each piece of equipment, and return Blue Machine 7 as that was in the text

Comment: Honestly, I'd need a little more (and you should edit your initial post to show your input and desired output). With what you just gave me, as specific as it is you can use a for loop to iterate through the desired strings to effectively do `re.findall('(Blue[\s]*Machine[\s]*7)', string)`, `re.findall('(Purple[\s]*hammer)', string)`, etc. and that doesn't seem like what you want based on your initial post